How can I make the instances turn around relative to the center of the circle-curve in geonodes?
I am creating a procedural lavender generator using curves and ran into the problem that I cannot deploy instances located along the curve-circle in the direction from its center. I managed to do this using the tangent of the curve at the node of the curve translation into points. But when connecting this node system to the stem node, the rotation of the instances becomes chaotic, and I cannot understand what the problem is.
It is also very important for me to keep the possibility of random distribution of instances along the curve, I just need to set up their orientation correctly. I'm just starting to learn geometric knots, so I don't know how difficult my situation is, but I haven't been able to cope with it for several hours.
I really hope for the help of people who are well versed in this. Thank you in advance!





"Tangent" is a "direction" not a "rotation".
If you use it, the results will be really strange.
You must "align rotation to vector" to make rotations make sense.
But the vector you want is the "normal" of the curve circle, not the tangent.
And then you must "rotate (the) rotation" using the rotation of the circle itself.

